# "Use Strict" - Waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Ao fazer o código em jQuery para um website deparei-me com o erro `"use strict"`. Este erro acontece mais exatamente na linha 2 `"Missing 'use strict'"` não deixando executar o mesmo. Precisava de ajuda na resolução do mesmo se possível.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('jq--secaaestcb').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === "down") {
            $('nav').addClass('nav-scroll');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('nav-scroll');
        }
    }, {
      offset: '60px;'
    });
});
```

Comment: Olá Paulo! Qual é o erro que te dá? Podes colocar aqui o texto do erro?

Comment: Boa tarde. O erro que aparece é " Missing 'use strict' statement" mais exatamente na linha 2, não sendo assim possível executar o código.

Comment: Não vejo razão para esse erro no código. Tens mais código do que esse? tens a certeza que é nesse ficheiro?

Comment: Sim é. :/ é o único código de jq que tenho. Estou a utilizar o dreamweaver não sei se faz diferença.